# Not able to restore activity on changing screen orientation

Tags: android

I'm just starting out on learning Android development, and this is a hurdle I'm stuck at.

Despite using `savedInstanceState` , everytime I change my screen orientation, I lose the activity, and a new activity is created. Here's the code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
    mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });
    mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });

    mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1)%(mQuestionBank.length);
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    mPreviousButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
    mPreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + mQuestionBank.length - 1)%(mQuestionBank.length);
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });

    updateQuestion();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX);
        }


}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
}
```

I created `private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";` outside the onCreate function.

Where is it that I'm messing up? Also, I want to try and do it without `onRestoreInstanceState` for no reason, but just learn every way possible.

Answer (score 0):

saveInstanceState doesn't prevent the destruction of the activity, it just allows you to restore it in onRestoreInstanceState.  If you want to completely stop that behavior, add android:configChanges="orientation" to your manifest.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But why doesn't the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState) say anything about that?

Comment: Also, how do I do it without using 'onRestoreInstanceState' @gabesechan